# unlink returns error on document that's open by DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to unlink XML document after process is done via DOMDocument, but returns an error like below :

#### Error

```
unlink(packageSettings.xml): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I've tried below code `unsetting` that variable like below but not working.

#### Code

```
$xslDoc = new \DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load('/full/path/of/packageSettings.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xslDoc);
// do some operation
unset($xslDoc);  // I've tried this.
unlink('/full/path/of/packageSettings.xml'); // this returns above error
```

### Update : Updated the typo on `unlink` line.

Comment: `unset` or `unlink`?

Comment: “Resource temporarily unavailable” sounds like an HTTP error message, not something you would get from a file system?

Comment: `$xslDoc` is not a file. File is `'/full/path/of/packageSettings.xml'`.

Comment: unlink is for deleting files not unset'ing variables, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: unlink('/full/path/of/packageSettings.xml'); this deletes a file given a path. unset($array[0]); removes whatever is stored in $array at index zero

Comment: @u_mulder updated typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone updated typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: what OS is php running on? if this happens on MS Windows, it means some program is still holding an open file handle to the file, but if it's running on Linux/MacOS/*BSD, it's something else

Comment: I'm on windows. I've made sure no other program is using this, because this xml I'm downloading from some source.

Answer (score 1):

I've found other SO answer that states that using `gc_collect_cycles()` will solve a problem. And it does solve the problem. So new code is like :

```
gc_collect_cycles();
unlink('/full/path/of/packageSettings.xml');
```

But I'm still not sure what was the original root cause.

Comment: my best guess: your XPath handle prevents proper cleanup of the DOMDocument handle, thus `unset($xslDoc);` isn't enough, you'd need ```unset($xpath);unset($xslDoc);``` - you'd also need to delete any references to any DOMNode elements created during `// do some operation`, you can get a whole new variable scope by doing ```call_user_func(function(){// do some operation });```

Comment: @hanshenrik no luck. I've tried both `unset($xpath);unset($xslDoc);`;

Comment: Strange thing is I've other 2 xmls in same method, but getting error in this one only.